# Get value from dynamic dictionary without key

Tags: flutter, dictionary

I get a dynamic dictionary from an API. That means key and value change all the time. I want to access the value, but I don't know the key. Also in the Dictionary is every time only one item. Does anyone have a solution for this?

An example dictionary from the API

```
{
"34534567397645": "Example Text"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do sth like:

```
yourMap[yourMap.keys.first]
```